# Go to anchor with include or require

Tags: php, include, anchor, require

In my index.php I have a table with data from my database. Each row has a link to edit. The edit page is a form with a submit button. When I press the submit button the data is updated in the database, and below I have

```
<?php
require_once 'index.php';
?>
```

so it seems as I go back to the index-file.

However, I would like to jump to the edited data, such as index.php#2.

```
<?php
require_once 'index.php#' . $ID;
?>
```

of course returns

```
Warning: require_once(index.php#2): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in...
```

since there is no file called index.php#2, only index.php.

Altough if I go to index.php#2 in the browser it works as expected.

How can I jump to an anchor with include/require?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't be done like that. After the edit form is submitted you should redirect to the URL with an anchor tag, ie

```
header('Location: /index.php#'.$ID);
```

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm.. Although I realized another problem, but it is CSS related, I might have to make a new question.

The anchor is behind the navigation bar, so it looks like I go to #id+1.

You know a fast fix, or should I do another question? For now I just do header('Location: /index.php#'.$ID-1);

Thank you!